# Solr post.jar crashes with "content is not allowed in prolog"

Tags: post, solr, xml-parsing, web-crawler, sax

I'm trying to evaluate Solr, but can't start crawling websites with the recursive option on. Have searched all over for an answer but no luck.
Environment: Windows Server 2012 r2, java version "1.8.0_171", solr-7.3.0.

When running the post.jar tool I get the following error:

```
java -Dauto=yes -Dc=testcore -Ddata=web -Drecursive=2 -Ddelay=10 -jar post.jar http://localhost/

SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting web pages to Solr url http://localhost:8983/solr/testcore/update/extract
Entering auto mode. Indexing pages with content-types corresponding to file endings xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
Entering recursive mode, depth=2, delay=10s
Entering crawl at level 0 (1 links total, 1 new)
POSTed web resource http://localhost/ (depth: 0)
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool$PageFetcher.getLinksFromWebPage(SimplePostTool.java:1252)
        at org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool.webCrawl(SimplePostTool.java:616)
        at org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool.postWebPages(SimplePostTool.java:563)
        at org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool.doWebMode(SimplePostTool.java:365)
        at org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool.execute(SimplePostTool.java:187)
        at org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool.main(SimplePostTool.java:172)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool.makeDom(SimplePostTool.java:1061)
        at org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool$PageFetcher.getLinksFromWebPage(SimplePostTool.java:1232)
        ... 5 more
```

I can index all links (to files and to other pages) in http://localhost/ manually if I do one by one with the recursive option off, so I don't think there are any files or links with special characters. Thank you all, your help is appreciated.

Comment: If somebody can recommend another crawler to use with Solr (and is friendly to configure in Windows) that'd be good too.

Comment: Have a look at Apache Nutch. It is specifically designed for crawling and can push data to Solr.

Comment: Hi @AlexandreRafalovitch, I did try to configure Nutch following their tutorial https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial , but had no success; followed several troubleshooting steps including adding hadoop libraries, adding environment variables, but couldn't get it to work either. Do you know of a good tutorial to set it up in Windows? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try Apache NiFi, if you have problems with Nutch: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/nifi-in-depth.html#webcrawler-template

Comment: Thank you @AlexandreRafalovitch for your answer. I couldn't get the post.jar tool to work correctly. After trying and troubleshooting Nutch 1.8 I was finally able to have it crawl webpages and follow links automatically. 
This is what I did: Install cygwin, install/extract Nutch to cygwin/home folder,  download Hadoop-0.20.20-core.jar and paste to cygwin/home/apache-nutch-1.8/lib.
After doing this I was able to complete the Nutch tutorial here: https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

Answer (score 1):

Remove the -Drecursive=2 , it was creating issue use the below command.

java -Dauto=yes -Dc=testcore -Ddata=web -Ddelay=10 -jar post.jar http://localhost/

Comment: wouldnt removing the recursive option just cause indexing the landing page?
I am having the same issue, was able to get each link individually but performing it for an entire site is too tiresome and length process and chances of duplication and missing out links are always there.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the post.jar tool to work correctly. After trying and troubleshooting Nutch 1.8 I was finally able to have it crawl webpages and follow links automatically. 
This is what I did: Install cygwin, install/extract Nutch to cygwin/home folder,  download Hadoop-0.20.20-core.jar and paste to cygwin/home/apache-nutch-1.8/lib.
After doing this I was able to complete the Nutch tutorial here: https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial
There were a few other minor hiccups along the way, but I don't really remember what those were (I need to work on better documentation...), anyway if anybody is trying this in a similar environment to mine, feel free to send me a message.

Answer (score 0):

With Drupal I solved this with a 6 line shell script no need for nutch, etc and the R&D, environment headaches etc that this entails:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=0
while [ "$x" != "37142" ]
do
        /opt/solr/bin/post -c drupal_dev  https://www.[yoursite].com/node/$x
        let "x+=1"
done
```

You could dynamically generate the highest node number using drush.

You could easily adapt this to use a list of URLs generated by using wget to crawl your site, or simply post them as wget crawls your site. I plan to do this if I get push-back from marketing about using /node/[nodeId] urls.

This particular shell script is slow enough that I didn't even need to throw in a delay.